# Set content-type header to json for request.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-headers, http-post, content-type

I am using "hackathon-starter" node bunch for my project. In this build when I try to call a API from request.post it will take "Content type `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'` header for all API. I have tried to change header from API calling but it will take only

> Content type :  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'

header for all API. I have tried below code. I want to set **application/json** for all API.

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
      var request     = require('request');

      var form = {
        "userType": req.body.type,
        "userName": req.body.mobile,
        "email": req.body.email,
        "name": req.body.name,      
        "password": req.body.password
      };  

      var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
      var contentLength = formData.length;
      request.post({
          headers: {'content-type':'application/json'},
          url:'mylink',
          form:    formData // I have tried form as well.
      },function(error, response, body){
      console.log(body)
    });
```

My error message on console.

> {"timestamp":1484822264270,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' not supported","path":"mylink"}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you need to use `json` option instead based on your requirements:

```
  var form = {
    "userType": req.body.type,
    "userName": req.body.mobile,
    "email": req.body.email,
    "name": req.body.name,      
    "password": req.body.password
  };  

  request.post({
      url:'mylink',
      json: form,
  },function(error, response, body){
  console.log(body)
});
```

From the options documentaion:

> **json** - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds
>   Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the
>   response body as JSON.

Comment: I have no words for your help many many thanks (multiply * 10K ) :) .